Entity List in Dynamics 365 Power Portal not showing recently updated data
I have an Entity List in a Dynamics 365 Power Portal Web Page.
Here are the various components
Power Portal
-- Web Page (Information)
-- -- Web Page (Content)
-- -- -- List

The list is connected with a view created in make.powerapps.com
From my power portal, I make an AJAX request to a Dot Net Web API to update some data in Microsoft Dataverse. The Dot Net Web API uses the Dataverse SDK for this purpose.
The Dot Net Web API returns successful response every time, and using XrmToolbox I can also see that the data has been actually updated in Dataverse.
However, in Power Portal, the list does not show the updated data until 10-15 minutes have elapsed.
I have enabled "Change Tracking" on the entity, but no improvements occurred.
Can you please help me figure out this issue?

This is normal and expected, the delay is caused by the very aggressive caching behind the Portal.
When the changes are performed from something that isn't the Portal itself (i.e. submitting a form) or a synchronous transaction (i.e. Real-Time Workflows, Plugins) it takes up to 15 minutes for the updates to show up, as per your current experience.
I have not yet had the chance to try it so it's only a hypothesis, but the Portal API might help in a scenario where you need to perform some changes to the data, there is no clear mention of it being "in real time" but I would expect it to be... I'd give it a try and see if it does the trick, and then see about porting your interactions over:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-pages/configure/write-update-delete-operations

You can perform available Web API operations in portals. Web API operations consist of HTTP requests and responses. This article provides sample write, update, and delete operations, methods, URI, and sample JSON you can use in the HTTP requests.

